# Confusing of TTimeSpan usage in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, record, timespan

I tried the new Record type TTimeSpan in Delphi 2010. But I encourage a very strange problem.

```
assert(TTimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000).Milliseconds = 5000);
```

This assertion does not pass. The value of 'TTimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000).Milliseconds' is expected to be 5000, but it was 0.

I dig deeper:

```
function TTimeSpan.GetMilliseconds: Integer;
begin
  Result := Integer((FTicks div TicksPerMillisecond) mod 1000);
end;

FTicks = 50000000
TicksPerMillisecond = 10000
FTick div TicksPerMillisecond = 50000000 div 10000 = 5000
(FTick div TicksPerMillisecond) mod 1000 = 5000 mod 1000 = 0 // I do not understand, why mod 1000
Integer((FTick div TicksPerMillisecond) mod 1000) = Integer(0) = 0
```

My code interpretation is correct, isn't it?

UPDATE: The method GetTotalMilliseconds (double precision) is implemented correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing the properties giving **the total amount expressed in a given unit** with the properties giving **the portion of a value when you break it up into its components** (days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, ticks).

With those, you get the integer remainder for each category. So, **`Milliseconds` will always be between 0 and 999** (Number Of Milliseconds Per Second - 1).
Or, another example, if you have **72 minutes, `TotalMinutes` is 72, but `Minutes` is 12**.

It is very much **similar to the `DecodeDateTime` function to break up a `TDateTime`**.

And for what you want to achieve, you definitely need to use the `TotalMilliseconds` property, as TridenT pointed out, but the code for `GetMilliseconds` is indeed correct in `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Thanks Francois, now I understand the logic.

Answer (score 3):

You must use `TotalMilliseconds` instead of `Milliseconds` property.

It works better !

```
assert(TTimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000).TotalMilliseconds = 5000);
```

From documentation:

> TotalMilliseconds    Double
>   Timespan expressed as milliseconds and
>   part milliseconds

Comment: Hey Dude, Thanks, this works! 

The wrong result of Milliseconds does have confused me. IMO, TTimeSpan is an immutable data type, so any modification should return a new Instance. 

I suppose, GetTotalMilliseconds returns a value at double precision and GetMilliseconds returns a value at integer precision. Anyway the implementation of GetMilliseconds seems to be very much incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand the `Milliseconds` property ! And the help file doesn't really .. well ... helps !